# Y-адаптер для LAN. И не работает - почему?

Tags: lan

Доброго всем.
Собрал Y-адаптер для LAN.Подключил 1-2-3-6 на одну розетку и соответственно 4-5-7-8 на вторую.В первой коннект есть, во второй нет.Протестил коннект LAN-тестером
итог:
вход 1236 = выход 1236
вход 4578 = выход 1236
(схему брал <a href="http://www.skomplekt.com/files/goods/4523464780/y_e2_e2_shema.gif">тут</a>)
Ведь всё верно! Почему не работает?

---

О! А что, теги основные отменили (я про a href)?

Comment: to: @MrClon, Точно! Вспомнил, как много лет назад делал!  Точно! Я же брал 1236  и как-то там что-то мудрил под руководством гуру IT-связистов.Соответственно на втором канале (4578) ничегошеньки нет!!! Это пустой же канал при 100 м\бит.И ещё вот, нашёл эту розетки двойник:http://ydoma.info/photos/kompyuter/vitaya-para/rj45-podklyuchenie-rozetki/rj45-rozetka-2x.jpgА схемы распиновки нет и какой у неё вход тоже не понятный, может там вход 1-2-3-6-1-2-3-6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@I_CaR](/users/1270/i_car), если я ещё хоть что-то понимаю в езернетах то с другого конца провода у этой розетки должны быть два штекера RJ45. А если он один то он должен вставляться в RJ45-гнездо от которого идёт провод в заканчивающийся двумя штекерами RJ45.

В общем это не разветвитель, это способ сделать из одного 8-жильного кабеля два 4-жильных в одной оплётке. Это широко распространённая практика при монтаже езернетовых сетей в офисах например, там где ненужен гигабитный езернет и не хочется тянуть лишние кабели. Я не могу понять, тебе именно это нужно или надеешься сделать «разветвитель» для ethernet? Последнее не получится. А если всё-таки первое то просто работай так какбуд-то это два 4-жильных кабеля по всей длинне линка, вплоть до свича (или что там у тебя).

Comment: @MrClon, Вот ещё что нащёл по моему типу.  http://www.peakelec.co.uk/art/econ.gifЕсли приходит со свича обычный единичный Ethernet, то с него такой (типа сплиттер) не как не выйдет?Нужно же и на другом конце 4578, пускать в 1236? Допустим на коммутаторе?Всё! Теперь вспомнил, что на свиче делал разрез одного и выпарывал из него (4578) на второй вилку в коммутатор в 1236!Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: >Если приходит со свича обычный единичный Ethernet, то с него такой (типа сплиттер) не как не выйдет?Да, не выйдет. Где-то этот кабель должен разветвляться на два и втыкаться в конце концов в два ethernet-порта. Если такой кабель втыкается в один ethernet-порт, и к нему нормально подключаются два устройства, значит на самом деле этот «один ethernet-порт» — два ethernet-порта сведённые в одну дырку каким-то сумрачным гением с паяльником.

Answer (score 0):

поставь такие разветвители с 2х сторон
будет на одном конце 2 входа , а на втором 2 выхода и все будет работать.
Но,если манипуляции только на одном конце , работать будет только 1 выход.
И да, вместо 1 гигабита будет 100 Мгабит